# Wait until SQL Server request end

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a lambda script that insert S3 Excel file data into a SQL Server database.

The only problem that I encounter is that my loop didn't wait until my database execution is finished.

Here is my code :

```
for(var key in data)
{
    var proj = data[key].project_id;

    request.input('proj_id', sql.Int, proj);            
    request.execute('ImportProject', function (err, recordset)
    {
         if(err)
         {
             callback(err);
             sql.close();                           
         }
         else
         {
            console.log('Project Insert : ', proj_id);
            sql.close(); 
            context.succeed; 
         }
     });                        
  }
```

Any idea how can I handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use async library to acheive the result. As I don't have database server setup I am writing the sample code here with comments. 
In your case you should use waterfall function which behaves like synchrous function.

Install : `npm install --save async`

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        // database connection in this  function if sucessfull connection happend call  the callback 
       // which contains the first parameter as error and others are input to next function
        callback(null, 'connection');
    },
    function(connection, callback) {
        //loop here, and finally callback after success 
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
    // final calculation here 
});
```

Please follow the async document for more information. 
https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html